# Plotting nullclines for a planar system of non-linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

A past exam paper I'm working on (Mathematics BSc, second-year module in differential equations, unpublished) has a question to plot the nullcline diagram of the system of ODEs,
\begin{align}
& \dot{x} = 2x - 2x^2 -xy, \\
& \dot{y} = 2y - 2y^2 - 3xy.
\end{align}
I found 4 equilibrium points, namely $(0,0),\;(0,1),\;(1,0),\;(2,-2)$. When I try to find the nullclines I get linear equations,
\begin{align}
& y = 2 - 2x, \\
& y = 1 - \frac{3}{2}x
\end{align}
but these can't intersect at all 4 of the equilibrium points. This makes me think I shouldn't be dividing through by $x$ or $y$, so as to preserve the quadratic shape, but in that case I can't see how to get the null equations in a form I know how to plot.

Could someone point out what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Comment: You're leaving out the null clines $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: @Gregory I thought the number of nullclines should be equal to the number of differential equations in the system. Also, using the set of 4 straight lines puts $(0,1)$ at the intersection of two $x$-nullclines and $(1,0)$ at the intersection of two $y$-nullclines, rather than each being at the intersection of an $x$-nullcline and a $y$-nullcline.

Comment: @mjc Only in linear ODE the number of nullclines is equal to number of equations. You've found all the 4 nullclines and the intersection are all the equilibrium points

Comment: @clarkmaio "Only in linear ODE the number of nullclines is equal to number of equations." is useful to know. I'm guessing that, if the ODEs are polynomials, the sum of the powers of the leading terms of the nullclines is equal to the sum of the powers of the leading terms in the ODEs? For this problem, I got one of the $x$-nullclines mixed up with one of the $y$-nullclines, so the 4 lines do seem to put all 4 equilibrium points at the intersection of one $x$- and one $y$-nullcline.

Comment: @mjc are you sure? What if $\dot x = \sin y$ and $\dot y = \cos x$. Will you have two null clines then?

Comment: @Moo Yes, that seems to have been part of the problem, as pointed out by Gregory's initial comment.

Comment: @Gregory OK, how about this? If an ODE in the system is periodic then the number of nullclines can be infinite; if all ODEs are polynomials then the number of nullclines is equal to the sum of the number of distinct roots of the ODEs.